# How do i find the occurence of words of particular number

Tags: php, string, word-count

Hello guys I have a small question that suppose I have a string as

"Hello My name is XYZ"

Now I know I can find the length of the words as "Hello" has 5 characters and "My" has 2 characters. By using following code

```
$text = file_get_contents('text.txt'); // $text = 'Hello my name is XYZ';
$words = str_word_count($text, 1);
$wordsLength = array_map(
function($word) { return mb_strlen($word, 'UTF-8'); },
$words
);

var_dump(array_combine($words, $wordsLength));
```

But what if i want to find that the number of words with length 1 is 0. The number of words with lengths 2 is 2. The number of words with length 3 is 1 and so on till number of length 10

Note- I am considering the word length till there is a space Suppose there is a date in the data like 20.04.2016 so it should show me that the number is words with length 10 is 1.

and one more thing how do I find the average length for the words in the string.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `array_count_values()` on the `$wordsLength` array it will give a count of the string lengths there are.  If you use this and a template array (created using `array_fill()`) with the elements 1-10 and a value of 0.  You will get a list of all of the word counts...

```
$counts = array_replace(array_fill(1, 9, 0), 
             array_count_values($wordsLength));
```

will give...

```
Array
(
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 1
    [5] => 1
    [6] => 0
    [7] => 0
    [8] => 0
    [9] => 0
)
```

Comment: Thank you mate figured it out but there is one problem how should i count the Date or any special character as 1 word?

Answer (score 1):

**Hi  try this it works on the date and special chars,emojis**

[image]

```
$text = 'Hello 20.04.2016   my   faceface  is XYZ';

$words =preg_split('/\s+/', $text);

$wordsLength = array_map(
function($word) { return mb_strlen($word, 'UTF-8'); }  ,$words);

print_r($words);

//Get Average word Length
$avg=round(array_sum($wordsLength)/count($words),1);
//print Avg
print($avg);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

([Demo](https://3v4l.org/BnNRS))

```
$text = '    Hello 20.04.2016   my   incredibleness faceface  is XYZ    ';
```

Generate array of continuous visible characters

```
$words = preg_split('/\s+/', $text, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
array (
  0 => 'Hello',
  1 => '20.04.2016',
  2 => '',
  3 => 'my',
  4 => 'incredibleness',
  5 => 'faceface',
  6 => 'is',
  7 => 'XYZ',
)
```

Replace visible strings with their multibyte length **notice the simpler syntax**

```
$wordsLength = array_map('mb_strlen', $words);
array (
  0 => 5,
  1 => 10,
  2 => 1,
  3 => 2,
  4 => 14,
  5 => 9,
  6 => 2,
  7 => 3,
)
```

Group and count lengths

```
$lengthCounts = array_count_values($wordsLength);
array (
  5 => 1,
  10 => 1,
  1 => 1,
  2 => 2,
  14 => 1,
  9 => 1,
  3 => 1,
)
```

Establish an array of defaults, because `$lengthCounts` may have gaps

```
$defaultCounts = array_fill_keys(range(1,10), 0);
array (
  1 => 0,
  2 => 0,
  3 => 0,
  4 => 0,
  5 => 0,
  6 => 0,
  7 => 0,
  8 => 0,
  9 => 0,
  10 => 0,
)
```

Filter the counts to remove elements/counts that are out-of-range

```
$filteredCounts = array_intersect_key($lengthCounts, $defaultCounts);
array (
  5 => 1,
  10 => 1,
  1 => 1,
  2 => 2,
  9 => 1,
  3 => 1,
)
```

Overwrite the defaults with found counts to prevent gaps in the output

```
$gaplessCounts = array_replace($defaultCounts, $filteredCounts);
array (
  1 => 1,
  2 => 2,
  3 => 1,
  4 => 0,
  5 => 1,
  6 => 0,
  7 => 0,
  8 => 0,
  9 => 1,
  10 => 1,
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate this is what i wanted just a lil request what if i want to add a line like Number of words of length 1 is 1     Number of words of length 2 is 2            Number of words of length 3 is 1            Number of words of length 4 is 0

Comment: Don't add that redundant text into your array.  Show that when you loop the output.

Comment: just forgot   trim string  replace `$text` with `trim($text)`  also  we need the 'UTF8'  mb_strlen  does it consider it default?

Comment: Yes it does consider it default and i already replaced it with trim($text). Mate can i just ask you two thing if m not bothering you what if i want to find the length of most occurring word like "My name is xyz and his name is ABC" so here most occurring word is "is" and its length is 2 and the last thing is can you please tell me the code for loop output.

Comment: Sorry if m bothering you too much mate. You seem like the best person to ask about this stuff :D

Comment: Just set it if you think it is not already the default in your system.  `mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");`  there is absolutely no need to `mb_trim()`, the `preg_split()` takes care of that.  Please try your next steps before asking for more help.  If stuck, show me your 3v4l.org demo.